# Digital Ocean Dokku unable to select a buildpack

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, dokku

I am fairly new to Dokku and I am experiencing an issue.

I want to push my nodeJS app to my server (with the following structure):

[image]

When I push to my Dokku remote I get the following output, I've searched the web but can't find a solution, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by moving my .git location into the hapi.js folder.
The package.json has to bee in the root folder it seems.